# Scanning log file to determing object creation quantity

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, object

I am building a log parsing utility for blade chassis logs (the Dell M1000E specifically) and I was wondering what I could do in Python to code it to parse the log to determine how many blade servers are present, and then create that many many numbered blade objects.

Log snippet for visual reference (full log continues to 12 and has several hundred more lines):

$ racadm getversion -v

server-1    2.41.40.40 (07)        PowerEdge M620         iDRAC7       Y

server-2    2.41.40.40 (07)        PowerEdge M620         iDRAC7       Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to know is the number of blade servers, then a simple Unix shell script would do:

```
racadm getversion -v | awk '"server-"{print $1}' | uniq | wc -l
```

> 2

Using Python:

```
infile = open("yourfile.txt")

servers = set()
line = infile.readline()
while line:
  fields = line.split()
  if len(fields)>0 and "server-" in fields[0] and fields[0] not in servers:
    servers.add(fields[0])
  line = infile.readline()

print(len(servers))
```

Comment: If I were able to do so on the system itself, it'd be pretty easy and if I can, I'm open to correction, but here's a  bit more detail because I need to do this in windows. the CMC (Chassis Management Console) runs a BusyBox linux fork. We run the racdump and dumplogs command and capture the output as .txt files to look at on a Windows system. The shell on the CMC itself is also extremely locked down. 

Once the needed number of blade objects gets created, I'll end up capturing information pertaining to hardware, firmware, IPs, etc

Comment: @Dylan I feel your pain. I added a Python solution.